# Only one person lives between John and Dany, who likes apple

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, clauses, attachment-ambiguity

> Only one person lives between John and Dany, who likes apple.

In previous sentence, who likes apple?  2) Joe lives immediately above Kyle, who lives on an odd numbered floor ? I mean I'm not able to understand the word 'who' – is it referring to 1) John or Dany? 2) Joe or Kyle?

Comment: It is possible that the writer meant: *Only one person who likes apple lives between John and Dany*. But the meaning is not clear.

Comment: What is the source of the quotation?  Did you make it up?

Comment: To my (American) ear, "who likes apple" sounds incorrect in this context.  It would be correct to write "who likes Apple" (referring to the Apple computer company and/or its products).  It would also be correct to write "who likes apples" (referring to the kind of fruit).

Comment: Also, did you mean to write "Dany"?  "Dan" and "Danny" are more common nicknames for "Daniel".  "Dani" is a more common nickname for "Danielle", "Daniela", and "Daniella".  The name "Dane" is also more common than "Dany".

Comment: Dany is unambiguously the apple aficionado. The comma is responsible for this. However, there are better ways to say it that don't hinge this important fact on mere punctuation.

Comment: John And dany are names. This question was asked in school exam. A sentence from puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule, when statements are issued after conjunctions, unless explicitly stated, they apply to the last mentioned person. In this case, we infer that Dany likes the apples. The sentence structure could be reviewed though; it is unclear.